# VB.net WPF and Win 10 Toast Notifications

Tags: wpf, vb.net, toast

I'm trying to show toast notifications in Win 10 from vb.net WPF app.
1. I added `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to .vbproj file in the `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">` section.
2. I Added references to **Windows.Data** and **Windows.UI**
3. My code:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub BtnClick()
        Dim ToastN As ToastNotification = New ToastNotification("Test", "This is test notification.")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ToastNotification
    Public Sub New(Title As String, Message As String)
        Dim TempStr As String = $"<toast>
                                    <visual>
                                        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                                            <text>{Title}</text>
                                            <text>{Message}</text>
                                        </binding>
                                    </visual>
                                  </toast>"
        Dim xmlDoc As Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument = New Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(TempStr)
        Dim Toast As Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification = New Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification(xmlDoc)
        Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(Title).Show(Toast)
    End Sub
End Class
```

4. Button's **click** event is set to **BtnClick**

Application runs but doesn't do anything. Everything works fine just `...createTestNotifier(Title).Show(Toast)` doesn't work.

Could you please help.
What am I doing wrong?

[Source ZIP](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhuCIpoux6ePg9MOhzqSorCH2Ii14Q)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a shortcut of your app
with that:

```
private bool TryCreateShortcut()
    {
        string shortcutPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + string.Format("\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\{0}.lnk", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
        if (!File.Exists(shortcutPath))
        {
            InstallShortcut(shortcutPath);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void InstallShortcut(string shortcutPath)
    {
        // Find the path to the current executable
        string exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        IShellLinkW newShortcut = (IShellLinkW)new CShellLink();

        // Create a shortcut to the exe
        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetPath(exePath));
        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetArguments(""));

        // Open the shortcut property store, set the AppUserModelId property
        IPropertyStore newShortcutProperties = (IPropertyStore)newShortcut;

        using (PropVariant appId = new PropVariant(Utility.APP_ID))
        {
            ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.SetValue(SystemProperties.System.AppUserModel.ID, appId));
            ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.Commit());
        }

        // Commit the shortcut to disk
        IPersistFile newShortcutSave = (IPersistFile)newShortcut;

        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutSave.Save(shortcutPath, true));
    }
```